# Vue computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

If I need to access a computed property 20 times in one function, is it better to assign the value of it to a local variable first?

Would that improve performance?

Comment: It would be a microoptimization.

Comment: `DRY` when you use a same value over and over again IMO it's better to it stored in variable instead of referencing it everytime like, `obj.whatever`

Comment: Improve performance: No, since the value already exists and given that the computed property dependencies don't change while this `function` that uses it 20 times. (And really `DRY` is the way to go even with negligible performance tradeoffs isn't it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies ...
> [Computed Caching vs Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

Vue.js automatically cache the computed value, as long as their reactive dependencies don't mutate.

Storing it in a variable would be counter-intuitive.

Comment: Good catch! This should be the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it should be ... Thanks ;-)